# Can not query for non basic attributes JPA

Tags: jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have a DBTweet class which knows it's comments as list of other DBTweet-objects (@OneToMany) and which knows it's parent tweet (@ManyToOne) if it is a comment. Parent is set to null if the tweet is no comment.

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class DBTweet extends DBIdentified {

    @Basic
    Date publishedOn;
    @Basic
    String username;
    @Basic
    String text;
    @Basic
    boolean isAnswer;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    List<DBTweet> answers = new ArrayList<>();
    @ManyToOne
    DBTweet parent = null;
}
```

When i want to query for all tweets, that are no comments i want to use this query

```
@GET
@Path("/tweet/newestfirst")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response readNewestTweet() {
    final CriteriaBuilder builder = this.entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    final CriteriaQuery<DBTweet> query = builder.createQuery(DBTweet.class);

    final Root<DBTweet> from = query.from(DBTweet.class);

    final Predicate predicate = builder.isNull(from.get(DBTweet_.parent));

    final Order order = builder.desc(from.get(DBTweet_.publishedOn));

    query.select(from).where(predicate).orderBy(order);

    return Response.ok(this.entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList()).build();
}
```

But the **non-basic** properties of DBTweet are not known by the compiler.

It just says:
cannot find symbol
symbol:   variable parent
location: class de.ls5.wt2.DBTweet_

In the compiled file there are only the basic properties.

```
@StaticMetamodel(DBTweet.class)
public abstract class DBTweet_ extends DBIdentified_ {
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<DBTweet, Date> publishedOn;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<DBTweet, String> text;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<DBTweet, String> username;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<DBTweet, Boolean> isAnswer;

    public DBTweet_() {
    }
}
```

Why can't i find the answers or parent property in the compiled file?
How can i solve this?

Any ideas?

Comment: put code in the QUESTION, not somewhere else. Include what error you get when you use that query ...

Comment: i've added the code

Comment: As this reference shows, http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/query.html#metamodel   any List relation field should be generated in the `DBTweet_` as ListAttribute. If your JPA provider does not do that then they are doing it wrong and you should report a bug on them